# How to represent "1\0" + "2" as a single string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Given the code below:

```
alert(encodeURIComponent("1\0" + "2")); // shows 1%002
alert(encodeURIComponent("1\02"));      // shows 1%02
```

Why is there a difference in the output?

Comment: Can't tell what it being asked here.  Please clarify.

Comment: You have to escape the slash. `"1\\02"`

Comment: The reason I downvoted this: it appears to me, to be a completely pointless question. it's also vague.  You've provided no context for why you need to do this, or what your larger goal is.  You do provide code - two options! - but you don't describe what you see, or the difference between them.

Comment: Wow... Enough with the crucifying. It's a legit question. Each line gives a different result, so the question is, "How would one alter `"1\02"` to give the same result as when using `"1\0" + "2"`?"

Answer (score 2):

`\N` (in this case, `\0`) is the start of octal notation for a character code that can take up to 3 digits.

So, change `"\0"` to `"\000"`:

```
"1\0002"
```

Or:

```
alert(encodeURIComponent("1\0002"));
```

You can read more under the [Using Special Characters in Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals#Using_Special_Characters_in_Strings) heading of MDN's *Values, Variables, and Literals* page. This notation is listed as `\XXX`.